# AWS Lambda using Java - setting the configuration connection/socket timeouts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, connection-timeout

See here:
[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html)

> The connection timeout is the amount of time (in milliseconds) that
> the HTTP connection will wait to establish a connection before giving
> up. The default is 50,000 ms. To set this value yourself, use the
> ClientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout method.

I am trying to set the value myself, using:

```
ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
configuration.setConnectionTimeout(1900000);
configuration.setSocketTimeout(1900000);
```

Problem is, I am trying to update this value FROM WITHIN an AWS Lambda Java function. If I am calling an external lambda function, I can configure this before I make the call. This is what all of the documentation is showing examples of.

Is there a way I can add an **environment variable** or **programmatically** update the current AWS Lambda Java function connection and socket timeout from within itself?

**Further clarification:**

There is not a "client" invoking this lambda function. It is intended to be scheduled on the hour, triggered by the event type "CloudWatch Events - Schedule." The lambda itself places a request for one GET call that can take anywhere from 65 seconds to 140 seconds to run. The overall lambda time is currently extended to 5 minutes. The lambda's GET call fails right at the 50 second mark. The provided AWS documentation above references a default 50 second limit, with 3 retry attempts, both of which supposedly can be modified. However, I have been unable to modify the connection or socket timeout programmatically from the lambda's own code, or any parameter on the lambda itself. There has to be a way to configure this properly.

To an external service, over HTTPS. I fed it proxy settings and I verified the connection was correct and that it was the right call. In Postman, it takes 65+ seconds for any input or limit.

Please advise.

Comment: I think we need to clarify your scenario.  Let's say I am running the client and you are providing the lambda function... are you wanting your lambda function to modify my client's timeout waiting for it to finish?  If so, that is impossible for several different reasons... so you might want to explain what problem you are actually trying to solve (rather than how you are currently wanting to solve it), and perhaps we can find a solution or at least clarify why this isn't possible.  Otherwise, if you are looking for a different scenario, please clarify.

Comment: There is not a "client" invoking this lambda function. It is intended to be scheduled on the hour, triggered by the event type "CloudWatch Events - Schedule." The lambda itself places a request for one GET call that can take anywhere from 65 seconds to 140 seconds to run. The overall lambda time is currently extended to 5 minutes. The lambda's GET call fails right at the 50 second mark.

Comment: The provided AWS documentation above references a default 50 second limit, with 3 retry attempts, both of which supposedly can be modified.  However, I have been unable to modify the connection or socket timeout programmatically from the lambda's own code, or any parameter on the lambda itself. There has to be a way to configure this properly.

I added this section to the post body to help others understand at first read.

Comment: Okay, so... CloudWatch Lambda invocations are asynchronous, so it's not the caller's timeout that's giving you issues (which I initially thought you were trying to modify, and which wouldn't make sense, because the caller's connection is to the Lambda API, not to your function directly -- the caller here is CloudWatch).  The 50 seconds discussed here is the timeout when you make requests with the SDK from your (Lambda) code.  Are you making your long-running `GET` request to an AWS service, or to an external service?

Comment: To an external service, over HTTPS. I fed it proxy settings and I verified the connection was correct and that it was the right call. In Postman, it takes 65+ seconds for any input or limit.

Comment: So, your question seems to be "How do I configure the timeout for an HTTPS request I'm making in Java?"  It has nothing to do with Lambda, *per se,* or the AWS SDK's `ClientConfiguration`.

Comment: It is an AWS lambda making the call, and it was an AWS Toolkit property that caused the issue. See my self found solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It turns out the lambda was successful from the AWS console. It was only failing in Eclipse. The AWS Toolkit containing the AWS SDK gave this error:

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out

I made the code and AWS console changes described above, and it did not work. What it was a setting in the AWS Toolkit > Preferences as shown here:

[image: AWS Toolkit Preferences]

[image: Timeout configurations]

The above Timeouts were both set to 20000s, limiting the HTTPS calls I was making as described above. I updated this value comically high to test it, now it resolves in about 93s. The same call in that time period from Postman is also 93s.